# How to download large data file by java code where data is fetching in chunks?

Tags: java, file, download, fetch, chunks

I need to have my bulk data into a file. When I tried to write the data to a file in on shot, sometimes I get `OutOfMemoryException` in my java code. To handle this case I am trying to write different code where I need to open file once and `write the data to file in chunk` so that my heap memory does not grow. So I am `looking for the best approach` for this case. My source data will be a `rest service's response data`. and I will write that data to the destination file.

Please suggest me a best approach to write data into a file...

I am trying to handle this case by following logic...

- Open the output file as BufferOutputStream
- Get the response from the rest get request
- Convert that response into byte[]
- Write the byte[] to file by `buffOut.write(arr, 0, available);`
- Flush the fileBufferObject  `buffOut.flush();`
- And so on till we have data to write in file.

Comment: now your getting data from DB or file?

Comment: What is the data that you are talking about ?

Comment: What is size of your Data File?

Comment: Data File size is in 2GB or more than that.

Answer (score 0):

**Java Streams** looks very suitable option after taking your use case in consideration. Processing file is based on Java streams yield better results as compared to **file scanner , Buffered Reader or Java NIO using memory mapped files**.

Here is performance comparison of processing ability of various Java Alternatives:

File Size :-  **1 GB**

1. Sanner approach: Total elapsed time: **15627 ms**
2. Maped Byte Buffer: Exception in thread “main” java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
3. Java 8 Stream: Total elapsed time: **3124 ms**
4. Java 7 Files: Total elapsed time: **13657 ms**

Sample Processing Example is as below:

```
 package com.large.file;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Java8StreamRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Path file = Paths.get("c:/temp/my-large-file.csv");
        try
        {
            //Java 8: Stream class
            Stream<String> lines = Files.lines( file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );

            for( String line : (Iterable<String>) lines::iterator )
            {
               //System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long elapsedTimeInMillis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert((endTime - startTime), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        System.out.println("Total elapsed time: " + elapsedTimeInMillis + " ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to read stream data.. Plz read my question again as I updated this. Tq

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
URL url = new URL("http://large.file.dat");
Path path = Paths.get("/home/it/documents/large.file.dat");
Files.copy(url.openStream(), path);
```

[Chunked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) should not matter, unless you want to work with parts of a file, when the connection is likely to fail after a time.

You can use *compression* sending headers and wrapping the InputStream in a GzippedInputStream. Or use apache's **HttpClient** with out-of-the-box support.